# Sum Over Previous Rows with Condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to sum over a column provided a somewhat non-straightforward condition on the ordered column.

Please see the following example for what I am trying to do:

This is what I currently have..

```
--------------------------------------------------
 ID | Month | Days -----------> ID | Month | Days_Cumulative     
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2012/01 | 22 -----------> AB | 2012/01 | 22
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2012/02 | 23 -----------> AB | 2012/02 | 45
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2012/03 | 28 -----------> AB | 2012/03 | 73
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2013/07 | 11 -----------> AB | 2013/07 | 11
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2013/08 | 15 -----------> AB | 2013/08 | 99
--------------------------------------------------
```

And this is what I am hoping to achieve..

```
--------------------------------------------------
 ID | Month | Days -----------> ID | Month | Days_Cumulative     
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2012/01 | 22 -----------> AB | 2012/01 | 22
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2012/02 | 23 -----------> AB | 2012/02 | 45
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2012/03 | 28 -----------> AB | 2012/03 | 73
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2013/07 | 11 -----------> AB | 2013/07 | 11
--------------------------------------------------
 AB | 2013/08 | 15 -----------> AB | 2013/08 | 26
--------------------------------------------------
```

My last row for the 'Days_Cumulative' column in the first table is 99 and it should be 26 as I'm trying to sum the days for only continuous months (my logic currently sums all rows for a specific ID). Now, I know why my query is giving me the results it is, however, what I don't know is how to get what I'm looking for. Basically, I want the

```
 Sum(T1.DAYS) over(partition by T1.ID order by T1.Month)
```

piece to re-start the sum once a new continuous-month-streak has started. My query may be a little messy - provided I'm joining onto my source table twice - but I have just been working at this one step at a time and can't find a solution anywhere for my particular problem.

Here is my query:

```
WITH SRC AS
(Select ID, Month, Days 
, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by Month) RN
from TABLE)
Select T1.ID, T1.Month, T1.Days
, CASE WHEN MONTHS_BETWEEN(T1.Month, T2.Month) > 1 THEN T1.DAYS
ELSE Sum(T1.DAYS) over(partition by T1.ID order by T1.Month) END AS Days_Cumulative
from SRC T1
Left Join SRC T2
On T1.ID = T2.ID
and T1.RN = T2.RN - 1 
Left Join SRC T3
On T1.ID = T3.ID
and T1.RN = T3.RN + 1
```

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define periods of contiguous months.  There are several ways to do this.  I would go for a difference using `row_number()`:

```
select id, month, days,
       sum(days) over (partition by id, grp order by month) as running_days
from (select . . .,
             add_months(month, -row_number() over (partition by id order by month)) as grp
      from . . .  -- not really sure what goes here
     ) t;
```

Note that your query and your sample data are quite different.  The above shows structurally what should be done.  You'll have to adapt it for your actual tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can create group based on continuity and then find cumulative sum within the groups:

```
with cte
as (
    select ID,
        Month,
        Days,
        case 
            when to_date(month, 'yyyy/mm') 
            = lag(add_months(to_date(month, 'yyyy/mm'), 1)) 
                    over (order by Month) 
            then 0 else 1 end x
    from table
    )
select
    t.*,
    sum(Days) over (partition by grp order by month)
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(x) over (order by Month) grp
    from src t
) t;
```

Comment: Tried this and it works perfectly. Thanks for the quick feedback!

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) try `select to_date('2014/10', 'yyyy/mm')` and see what happens (if you don't understand, read the documentation); (2) study Gordon's more efficient solution - the trick he used is a variant of the "tabibitosan method" for gaps and islands problems.

Comment: Oh - and I just noticed: You had a "comment" asking the OP to mark your solution as the "correct" answer, then when he did, you deleted it? So you must know that's not entirely ethical? (Otherwise why delete it?)

Comment: Are you sure you want to continue this discussion? If it's just to help posters, why do you **delete** the comment asking the OP to mark your answer as Correct, after they do so? Won't your "gentle reminder" help other new members, in the future? Here's some discussion about this on SO many years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes And in this case, keep in mind that Gordon's answer is, in fact, superior (something the OP seems to have concluded on his or her own) - the Tabibitosan method requires one less subquery than the "start of group" method.

Comment: @mathguy - You are absolutely right as always. I will not ask anyone to accept any answer from now on. Thanks for the feedback as always. "begging for votes" is a bit too much though.

Comment: I did find that Gordon's solution worked better for my circumstance. I appreciate the help from everyone and didn't mean to be disrespectful by changing my answer to which was "correct". In GurV's defense, I wouldn't have known to accept the answer unless told - so thanks for the help! I simply had a problem, I asked what I thought was a straightforward question and got two very helpful answers. I think we should just leave it at that, since it's what the site is for. Thanks again.